# Sci-Fi book about a virus and maybe a meteor?

Tags: story-identification

The book I originally heard on tape, but remember reading it but cannot remember the name.
It starts with someone in a submarine or diving in the ocean where he becomes trapped by an underwater rock slide or some type of accident and the person in charge of the expedition asks about the rocks.  The line I remember specifically from the the book was "I'm going to die down here, and he's asking about the F**king rocks."

Later on in the story, there are people doing research on a space station where they're trying to find the answer to some virus or plague that has hit the earth.  The find that by simulating that you're pregnant stops the virus (they found this out because a female rat was pregnant).

Anyway, I can't remember the name of the book, and I've been searching for years. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192616/book-about-alien-eggs-found-in-an-asteroid-that-crashes-in-the-sea

Answer (score 10):

*Gravity: A Novel of Medical Suspense*, by Tess Gerritsen.  The exact quote is "I am going to die, and he is asking about the fucking rocks."  (I googled "asking about the fucking rocks" and it came up.)

Also, from the Amazon description:

> A young NASA doctor must combat a lethal microbe that is multiplying in the deadliest of environments -- space(...)

From Google Books, one character talking to another:

> "Why would pregnancy make a difference? Why should it be protective?" "(...)If we can mimic that state, maybe we can reproduce what's happened in that mouse."